# Is possible to use a smart contract with custom buyTokens method in TestNet?

Tags: solidity, remix, ropsten, rinkeby

I'm trying to test a smartcontract in TestNet that is working in my private ethereum blockchain network. I can deploy it in Ropsten and Rinkeby, but I can not execute my buyTokens method from Remix. My buyTokens have a not standard implementation, is a custom buyTokens:

```
    function buyTokens(address _wallet,uint256 _amount, uint coin) public
    isOwner
    isEnableToSend(_wallet,_amount, isBuying)
    returns(uint256,uint256)
    {
        _totalSupply = _totalSupply.add(_amount);
        balances[_wallet][coin] = balances[_wallet][coin].add(_amount);
        emit BuyTokens(_wallet,_amount,coin,Time_now());
        return (_totalSupply,balances[_wallet][coin]);
    }
```

I have coin 0 (EUR), coin 1 (USD), coin N (***), coin  10 (CAD), each wallet have funds in each coin type, is possible that TestNet is not allow me use this type of buyTokens method?

The error in Ropsten and Rinkeby is:
[image]

Comment: "is possible that TestNet is not allow me use this type of buyTokens method"--unlikely. It's difficult to tell what happened without seeing the code. My guess is that a condition in the modifier `isEnableToSend(_wallet,_amount, isBuying)` is not satisfied.

Comment: This smartcontract is currently deployed in a private network with an old geth version, recently this smartcontract was deployed in a private network whit latest stable version of geth and it's working, I don't know why is not working in Ropsten or Rinkeby

Comment: Interesting. Can you post a link to the full source?

Comment: Of the smartcontract code???

Comment: Yes. The contract code.

Comment: Sorry but it is in a private repository of my client, is not possible for me to share the code. I think it will finally continue to be tested on private networks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110532/discussion-between-hrkrshnn-and-conde).